# Reduce Time complexity

Tags: python-3.x, list, time-complexity

Question at hand : Complete the function minimumSwaps in the editor below. It must return an integer representing the minimum number of swaps to sort the array.

My Approach:

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    count = 0
    temp = [None]*len(arr)
    res1=sorted(arr)
    
    while(res1!=arr):
        for i in range(int(len(arr))):
            if(res1[i]!=arr[i]):
               y=res1.index(arr[i])
              
               arr[y] , arr[i]=arr[i] , arr[y]
               count = count +1

    
    return count
```

The code does give the required op for majority of the cases , but fails a few due to time limit exceeds error. Could someone suggest a few changes to reduce the time complexity issues and make the code more efficient. If Possible please try not to change the code in its entirety , I want to learn to make codes more efficient rather than trying a whole new approach altogether.

[Link to one of the huge test case](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/70816/input10.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1597769845&Signature=ZQALRWcODj1%2B9YyD%2BWLqGdDwI3k%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: compilation time error? are you sure that's correct? I could see it time-limit exceeding, but python doesn't compile...

Comment: Under the assumption that by compilation time error you mean it time-limit exceeds, I can say with quite good confidence that the only way to get a passing solution is with a complete code re-design

Comment: @JacobSteinebronn you got me , pardon my use of wrong terminologies. I did mean time limit exceeds , I got a suggestion from someone to use a dictionary instead of the index function but wasn't quite clear on how to do so. Anyway what would you suggest I do ?

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is a graph problem. Maybe it's possible with a more simple solution, but I don't think so.

You can observe that to get the minimum swaps necessary, you'd just have to move every element into its sorted position. You can figure out where they're supposed to be by sorting and having an array indexed by element (or dictionary, for that matter) to the index.

Now, build a graph by making each item its own node, and connecting with a directed edge to the place it needs to be. We can observe that for a cycle of length `k`, we will need `k-1` swaps to solve it. This is because we just need to swap each item forward, but the last swap actually solves *two* items rather than one. Thus, the answer is the sum of `k-1` for each cycle, which can be reduced to `n-c` where c is the number of cycles.

To see why this works, consider the case of `[2,3,1]`. The sorted version of this array is `[1,2,3]`. Now, build the graph, where index 0 points to index 1 (since 2 needs to be in index 1), index 1 points to index 2, and index 2 points to index 0. We can run a search algorithm through the graph and find the number of cycles or components, and find that there is 1 cycle of length 3. So, the answer we produce is 3-1 = 2. As we can observe, this is indeed correct.

The problem gets a little more complicated if the array can contain duplicates, but it's not so bad, you'd just have to think a little harder. Maybe this isn't the intended solution, but it'll certainly *work* in `O(n)`. Best of luck!